Can't access springboot application using nginx ingress controller in AKS

I am trying to access a springboot application deployed on AKS using nginx ingress controller  but i am always getting "Whitelabel Error Page" error as shown below.




URL I am using to access the service is :
http://<ingress-external-ip>/app1/greet



Below are my source code and kubernetes manifest files.
App.java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}

MyController.java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class MyController {
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> displayMessage() {
    System.out.println("app-1 received request");
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome to app-1");
  }
}

Application.properties
server.port=8080

manifest.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-1
  namespace: test-demo
  labels:
    tag: app-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tag: app-1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: app-1
      namespace: test-demo
      labels:
        tag: app-1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app-1
          image: user123/app-1:linux-amd64
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "2"
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 100Mi

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-1-svc
  namespace: test-demo
spec:
  selector:
    tag: app-1
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: test-demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-1-svc
                port:
                  number: 80


What I am doing wrong ?

The whitelabel error page is related to Spring, meaning that the request is coming through. Could you try modifying the @RequestMapping value to "/app1/greet" as well?

Tried replacing @RequestMapping("/greet") with @RequestMapping("/app1/greet") but still getting the same error.

It seems like there might be an issue with your ingress configuration. One possible solution could be to check if the path in your ingress YAML file matches the path in your URL.  Wait, sharing you the updated ingress yaml shortly. try that out

This can be caused by a mismatch between the ingress path and the controller request mapping. To deploy a Spring Boot application on an AKS cluster using an NGINX Ingress controller.
Install NGINX Ingress Controller under namespace ingress-nginx
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx



Deploy the Spring Boot Application (replace test demo with your own namespace)
# deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-1
  namespace: test-demo
  labels:
    app: app-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-1
        image: user123/app-1:linux-amd64
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

Create the service for the application
# service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-1-svc
  namespace: test-demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: app-1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080

Create the ingress resource (This is different from the ingress you tried)
# ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: test-demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-1-svc
                port:
                  number: 80

Apply all three
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml


Get the external IP of the NGINX Ingress Controller

Now map it with your own spring boot application
example
Application.java:
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}

MyController.java:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> displayMessage() {
        System.out.println("app-1 received request");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Welcome to app-1");
    }
}

application.properties:
server.port=<your-port-number>

References:

Deploy an ingress controller
Use ingress to expose services through externally reachable URLs

